# How can one respond to a vocal "Alert from Mathematica" as to replacing a file?

Tags: files-and-directories, warning-messages

Upon trying to overwrite an existing file, as I have done countless previous times, I was somewhat dumbfounded (this never happened before) to hear a voice: "Alert from Mathematica: such-and-such a file already exists. Do you want to replace it?"

How can I respond (I tried saying "yes", to no apparent effect--and couldn't seem to simply "replace" as usual)? How did this come about and how possibly could I simply turn it off (some Systems Preferences setting perhaps--I'm on a MacBookAir), if I so choose? Come to think of it, the other day I set a Speech option so that a voice could read some text in Preview--maybe this "Alert from Mathematica" is a byproduct of that setting.

Answer (score 1):

Upon further reexamination, I see the announcement is essentially "harmless", as I can proceed with the replacement of the file in the usual manner. The announcement is just a further "alert" to the (unspoken) message that the previous file already exists. I guess the original announcement ("out-of-the-blue") so startled me I "lost my bearings".